# Batch: How to exclude file names with extensions from a directory path in a text file?

Tags: batch-file

file.txt:

```
C:\Program Files\Folder\file.exe
```

Can be .exe, .dll, etc.

Output Goal:

```
C:\Program Files\Folder
```

Code so far:

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`type file.txt ^| findstr /vc:".exe"`) do ( echo %%g )
```

Comment: Take a look at the help information for the `for` command, `for /?`, and pay attention to its variable substitution modifiers.

Comment: Im not to sure how to use it, though how would this come in handy? Im getting this path info from a text file.

Comment: how about `echo %%~dpg` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example assumes that all your listed files all have an extension, *(comprising a period, followed by `2`, `3`, or `4` characters)*. To clarify, that means it will ignore any files or last leaf directories which have no periods, or end with a period followed by `1`, `5`, or more than `5`, characters; but will pick up last leaf directories which end with a period folowed by `2`, `3`, or `4` characters:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('%__AppDir__%findstr.exe /ER "\...$ \....$ \.....$" "file.txt" 2^> NUL')Do @For %%H In ("%%~dpG.")Do @Echo %%~dpnxH
```

Please note that, I've used `findstr.exe` directly in the example above. If you aren't getting the results intended it is likely that your source file, `file.txt`, is Unicode. In that case, you should revert to piping the content from the `type` command, as in your orginal posting:

```batch-file
@For /F Delims^=^ EOL^= %%G In ('Type "file.txt" 2^> NUL ^| %__AppDir__%findstr.exe /ER "\...$ \....$ \.....$"')Do @For %%H In ("%%~dpG.")Do @Echo %%~dpnxH
```

*The code could be made more robust if each of the items from the file, or the ones you require, existed within the system. (But that is currently out of the scope of your very limited question criteria).*

Comment: The second option worked, thank you very much. Also where should I go to learn about wildcard functions, and variable substitution?

Comment: Every single built in command has a help function, most often accessible using `commandname /?`, `help commandname`, and `commandname --help`. The information regarding wildcards and variable substitutions is available within the output from `for /?` and `findstr /?`. This site does not give advice on third party learning locations, so my advice is the built in help, _(as above)_, or to seek additional assistance from the official website for the manufacturer of the command or utility you require information on.